# Extending an existing type in Go

Tags: architecture, go

This is my first post here. I want to do the following with the help of [embedding in GO](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding),

1. extend the [`html.Tokenizer`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/html#Tokenizer) with new methods of my own
2. while still able to access all existing `html.Tokenizer` methods in
   the mean time
3. define a function `WalkBody()` (or an interface method if possible)
4. in which an interface method of `VisitToken()` is used, which will
   behave differently for different types

After an extended discussion in `[go-nuts]` mlist, I changed the sample code of 
https://github.com/suntong/lang/blob/master/lang/Go/src/xml/htmlParserTokens.go
to 
https://github.com/suntong/lang/blob/master/lang/Go/src/xml/htmlParserTokens2.go
according to all the suggestions there.

However, all suggestions so far just kept to one focus, but not all four altogether. E.g., the first two goals can be achieved by "type MyTokenizer struct", but as soon as I change that to the interface type to act as the base for the two different extended types (for goal#3&4), goal#2 breaks. I.e.,

this works,

```
type MyTokenizer struct {
    *html.Tokenizer
}

func NewMyTokenizer(i io.Reader) *MyTokenizer {
 z := html.NewTokenizer(i)
 return &MyTokenizer{z}
}
```

As soon as I tried the suggested following, everything started to break down.

```
type TokenVisitor interface {
    VisitToken()
}

func WalkBody(of TokenVisitor) {
    // here you call of.VisitToken()
}

type MyTokenizer1 struct {
    *html.Tokenizer
}

func (the MyTokenizer1) VisitToken() {

}

type MyTokenizer2 struct {
    *html.Tokenizer
}

func (the MyTokenizer2) VisitToken() {

}
```

Seem to me some compromise has to be made, what is the least compromise to make?

The actual purpose for me to ask this question is that, I have a *systematic* thinking in OO how to solve such kind of inherit & enhance problem, and there is a *practical implementation* in place for me, the virtual functions. But when it comes to Go, I still need help for how to think, and how to do.

Anybody can help please? Is there any *systematic* way to deal with the situations like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry,

Matt gave an answer this morning, @
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/FRE_A6cNzW8/lF10PeRrAAAJ

But I thought it wouldn't work at first, now after having thinking it over, and over, I finally make it working.

So it kind of answer the question, even it *feel* like spaghetti code, I'll
 still mark it as answered, for now.

If someone want to chip in, I'll be glad to accept your answer.

Comment: What's the issue? The code seems fine to me (the `htmlWalk` function could be split up a bit, but that's no big deal).

Comment: No issue, when I asked the question, I didn't think there is an answer, but later I found Matt's answer is a good one, hence _both_ the question and answer here, @doubleYou.